# Solution for coupled non linear differential equation in Python or SageMath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

How to solve four first order coupled non-linear differential equations using python or SageMath? Please suggest some references if available. Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python and the scipy module's odeint, import as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

A fun example is that of "Modeling a zombie apocalypse, see:
https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Zombie_Apocalypse_ODEINT.html